# Sinatra print string on webpage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am trying to print process status on webpage. But when execute `host:port/status` method I dont see any response. It returns a blank page. ps -ef command executes on command line. I tried printing it on getStatus Method but it doesnt print it.

I want to display process execution status on website.

```
def getStatus
        puts #{system('ps -ef | grep abc.jar|grep -v grep')? "Running": "Stopped"}
        return #{system('ps -ef | grep abc.jar|grep -v grep')? "Running": "Stopped"}
end

get '/status' do
     return getStatus
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression

```
puts #{…
```

will only print a newline character, since `#` outside a string introduces a comment, same with `return #…`.

To get the actual output, use something like this (I took the freedom to transformed your code snippet into more idiomatic Ruby):

```
def running?
  `ps -ef` =~ /abc\.jar/
end

get '/status' do
  status = running? ? 'Running' : 'Stopped'
  logger.debug "Status: #{status}"
  status
end
```

---

Now the `running?` method performs your check:

1. get the result of `ps -ef` via [Kernel#`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-60)
2. match that result against the [regular expression](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/doc/regexp_rdoc.html) `/abc\.jar/` via [String#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-3D-7E) (basically perform `grep abc\.jar` in Ruby land)

Step 1 is performed in a sub shell and everything in the sub shell is returned into Ruby land, whereas [Kernel#system](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-system) will only return whether the command exited with a non-zero exit status. Any output from commands started with `system('...')` is also redirected to stdout Your inital code snippet would not have worked that way, since `grep -v grep` will always exit with status `0`.

(technically, a sub shell is not required, but the [IO.popen](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/IO.html#method-c-popen) call is more complex)

Comment: Thanks you. I can see it printing value on the webpage. can you explain a little bit about ps -ef in running method. How does it evaluate it. I am new to ruby.. sorry for asking simple Q.

Comment: I've expanded my answer above. I'd strongly suggest to read the linked documentation.

Comment: thanks a ton. You are also gave me a lot of valuable links. appreciate it.

Comment: I am wondering if you have to use the `ps -ef` =~ /abc\.jar/ inside a if case instead of a method. How can i do it? Thanks.

Comment: You mean like [this](http://www.intridea.com/blog/2010/3/29/ruby-quick-tip-regular-expressions-in-case-statements)?